# Root generation error? Cannot find entry file index.android.js (React Native)

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

> "Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: 
>       [/"c:////Users////Sekf////Documents////GitHub////TestProjOne/"]"

I started a react native project from scratch using `react-native init ProjName`. It gives me an error on the first run. This is the error I'm getting in the console. I realize there are lots of other question asking basically the same things and I've tried pretty much every fix I could find. Also, the error that I'm getting is a bit different since there are way too many backslashes in between each directory and no other post has had a similar error.

Here is what I've already tried:

1. Start packager with `npm start -- --reset-cache`
2. Start packager with `npm start -- --root '/my/project/root/'`
3. Tried downgrading to react-native v0.44.0 as well as many other version
4. Tried downgrading react to a few different versions
5. Basically tried multiple different versions of every dependency in the initial react native app
6. Double check android studio settings. I've gone through the react native docs multiple times. No luck.
7. Re-installed everything: Android Studio, Node, npm, react-native-cli, JDK

I'm completely at a loss.